# to write a c program using switch case to find whether a character is vowel or consonant

Tags: c

```
include
include
void main() {

    char ch;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter a character:");
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    switch(ch) {
        case 'a': case 'A': case 'e': case 'E': case 'i': case'I': case'o': case'O': case'u': case'U':
            printf("Vowel");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Consonant");
            getch();
    }
```

to also give a feature that if we give input as a number or some special characters like @,# etc its should show invalid not consonant.

Comment: Please read how to [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Comment: In your code, a space is also considered a consonant.

Comment: You may want to filter the characters that get to your `switch` statement if you really want to use this approach.

Comment: actually sir I am totally new at stackoverflow, in my code i want to add a logic which will show "invalid" as a output if i give input as 2,3,4,@,&, etc but its showing consonant which means code is not fully correci i have tried but i am not able to get proper output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `isalpha()` to see if a character is a letter or not. And you can cut the number of `case` statements you use by converting the character into lowercase using `tolower()`, which makes the code simpler and less likely you'd miss something.

```
if(isalpha(ch)) {
    switch(tolower(ch)) {
        case 'a':
        case 'e':
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'u':
            printf("Vowel");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Consonant");
        break;
    }
} else {
    printf("Invalid");
}
```

Comment: sir one error is showing as "misplaced else" but thank you for the help sir

Comment: @jyotimalik - the `else` is not misplaced. although its position may not be in the style you are used to, it is completely legal.  This is a good solution, and you should consider clicking the check mark symbol to the left of the answer.

Comment: sir now when i am giving input as consonant ,i am getting output as invalid not as "it is a consonant"

Comment: If you've replaced your `switch` code with the code I've written it should work as required

Comment: Don't pass plain `char` to `<ctype.h>` functions like that - always widen to `unsigned char` to avoid sign-extension.

Answer (score 1):

One option is `strchr`. It looks for the occurrence of a specific character inside a string, and is supposedly optimized well.

```
bool isvowel (char ch)
{
  return strchr("aeiou", tolower(ch)) != NULL;
}
```

And that's it. Full example:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool isvowel (char ch)
{
  return strchr("aeiou", tolower(ch)) != NULL;
}

int main (void)
{
  for(unsigned char i='A'; i<='Z'; i++)
  {
    char ch = (char)i;
    printf("%c: %s\n", ch, isvowel(ch) ? "vowel" : "consonant");
  }
}
```

Comment: And before some language lawyer comments: no, the example doesn't support EBCDIC. Which is a feature.

Comment: I'm just curious. Why `strrchr` instead of `strchr`? In theory, `strchr` can stop as soon as it finds a match but `strrchr` has to scan the whole string to find the last match.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I had some muddled thoughts about table lookups there, but not enough coffee. You are right, this doesn't make sense, I'll swap to strchr.

Comment: Why is producing wrong results a "feature"?  Would be better to get a compile-time warning than wrong results.  Actually, it does seem to work on EBCDIC systems, as long as you consider `«»ðýþ±°ªºæ¸Æ¤µ~` to be consonants.

Comment: And you've made the common beginner mistake of passing plain `char` to `tolower()`.

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks for your timely feedback. It's a "feature" since people still working with EBCDIC in the year 2023 _deserve_ problems and giving them further incentive to finally do the porting they should have done some 40-50 years ago. As for passing `char` to ctype.h functions, that's fine as long as the input is sanitized. Input sanitation should not be done at the point where such a function is called but much earlier.

Comment: I'm not sure I approve of the double standard - ASCII good, EBCDIC bad?  Inflicting pain on everyone not still using 7-bit ASCII isn't any nicer than doing so to EBCDIC users.  (It wouldn't surprise me to learn that you consider US-ASCII to be the _only_ ASCII worthy of kindness).

Comment: @TobySpeight It is a huge waste of everyone's time to worry about portability to extremely outdated or fictional systems. Since all manner of ASCII as well as UTF8 allows iteration across letters, that's good enough for 99.999% of all use-cases. Literally the only ones who care are SO language lawyers, since those are plentiful compared to the number of users of EBCDIC and fictional systems.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
char ch;
printf("Enter a character:");
scanf("%c",&ch);
if((ch >= 65 && ch <= 90)||(ch >= 97 && ch <= 122))
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 'a':
            case 'A':
            case 'e':
            case 'E':
            case 'i':
            case'I':
            case'o':
            case'O':
            case'u':
            case'U':
                printf("Vowel");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Consonant");
        }

else
        printf("Invalid");
 }
```

In this I have used a concept of ASCII . Refer the ASCII values here.[image]

Comment: sir actually one error is coming as misplaced else but thank u for the help sir

Comment: I am not the down voter, but reproducing an ASCII chart as an image in your post may not be the best way to provide that information.  Although a picture is immediately illustrative (when image is high enough quality, which yours is not), it might better be provided as a _[link to an ASCII chart](http://www.asciitable.com/)_.

Comment: Ouch, use of magic numbers. Why use both `'a'` and `97`, for example?

Comment: required answer has came by using isalpha() thank u for the help sir

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to do this exercise, using a `switch()` is burning daylight. There's nothing preventing you from developing a custom version of the `<ctype.h>` functions to suit your needs.

Below is a 128 character table covering the 7-bit ASCII range. Each entry in that table has been assigned a letter to identify the type of the character at that location in the ASCII table. The translation of sample strings (shown below) shows the functionality.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void tx( char *cp ) {
    const char tbl[] =
        "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        "Spppppppbbppppppddddddddddpppppp"
        "pVCCCVCCCVCCCCCVCCCCCVCCCCCbpbpp"
        "pvcccvcccvcccccvcccccvcccccbpbpp" ;

    puts( cp );
    while( *cp )
        putchar( tbl[ *cp++] );
    puts( "\n" );
}

int main( void ) {
    char *smpl[] = {
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLM01234NOPQRSTUVWXYZ(,=$)",
        "abcdefghijklm56789nopqrstuvwxyz[,=$]",
        "Twas BRILLIG, & the Slithey toves did\t...",
        NULL,
    };

    for( char **ps = smpl; *ps; ) tx( *ps++ );

    puts(
        "Legend:\n"
        "\tX - control char\n"
        "\tS - SP(ace)\n"
        "\tp - punctuation\n"
        "\tb - bracket/brace\n"
        "\tC - consonant\n"
        "\tV - vowel\n"
    );

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLM01234NOPQRSTUVWXYZ(,=$)
VCCCVCCCVCCCCdddddCVCCCCCVCCCCCbpppb

abcdefghijklm56789nopqrstuvwxyz[,=$]
vcccvcccvccccdddddcvcccccvcccccbpppb

Twas BRILLIG, & the Slithey toves did   ...
CcvcSCCVCCVCpSpSccvSCcvccvcScvcvcScvcXppp

Legend:
        X - control char
        S - SP(ace)
        p - punctuation
        b - bracket/brace
        C - consonant
        V - vowel
```

Comment: What do you do with negative `char`?  It's quite brave to assume that all input will be in ASCII range.

Comment: @TobySpeight "_Below is a 128 character table covering the 7-bit ASCII range._" ... Caveat emptor... `:-)`

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
char ch;
int a;
printf("Enter a character: ");
scanf("%c",&ch);
a=ch;                   // Here im converting the character into its ascii form 
if (a >= 65 && a <= 90)
a=a+32;                     /* upper case into lowercase by adding 32 to it*/
ch=a;
if(a >= 97 && a <= 122)
    switch(ch)
    {
        case 'a':
        case 'e':                                  
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'u':
            printf("\nThe given character is a Vowel");
        break;
        default:
            printf("\nThe given character is a Consonant");
    }

else
        printf("Invalid Input");                     
}
```

Comment: Your case conversions relies on the implementation  using ASCII encoding (which it is *not* required to do). Better to use the standard library function, `tolower`.

Comment: As you can see I was trying to do this without the use use of a function, so this was for someone who didn't know functions yet, that's why, thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Never ignore the return value of `scanf()` and family.  In this case, we'll blindly continue past end of input.